# Using Apache PDFBox in Oracle JVM

Tags: oracle, jvm, pdfbox

I'm trying to load the Apache PDFBox Java libraries into the Oracle JVM but seem to get lost in unresolved dependencies.
Did someone success to load PDFBox 2.0.8 into a Oracle 12.2 JVM?

Comment: See the dependencies page https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html or download the pdfbox-app file. If it doesn't work, please edit your question to show the errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s mostly a problem on how to resolve the java dependencies and once that’s done, everything works as expected by loading the packages in the following order:

1) Load the “Bouncy Castle” dependencies

```
loadjava -resolve -user scott/tiger@localhost:1521:orcl -thin bcprov-jdk15on-158.jar bcmail-jdk15on-158.jar bcpkix-jdk15on-158.jar
```

2) Load “Apache common logging”

```
 loadjava -resolve -genmissing -user scott/tiger@localhost:1521:orcl -thin commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

3) Load “Apache PDFBox”

```
 loadjava -resolve -user scott/tiger@localhost:1521:orcl -thin fontbox-2.0.8.jar pdfbox-2.0.8.jar pdfbox-tools-2.0.8.jar pdfbox-debugger-2.0.8.jar
```

And now using PDFBox works like a charm!

Comment: To use PDFBox 2.0.21 you need Bouncy Castle 1.66 jars.