# Using Apache PDFBox in Oracle JVM 11.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jvm, pdfbox

I'm trying to load the Apache PDFBox Java libraries into the Oracle JVM but seem to get lost in unresolved dependencies. Did someone success to load PDFBox 1.8.13 into a Oracle 11.2 JVM?

The solution in [Using Apache PDFBox in Oracle JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788278/using-apache-pdfbox-in-oracle-jvm/48432973#48432973]) works for Oracle 12C. Does anyone has the recipe for Oracle 11G.
Thanks

Comment: "Did someone success" is the wrong question to ask. You should post your actual technical problem and what you have tried.

Comment: Which are the unresolved dependencies? Post the exact error message you get...